# What is the correct number of points to use in a response function for colvolutions?

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

I have an input function/data - f(x) - and I want to convolute it with a response function - g(x) - to obtain an output function - h(x). I've verified that the number of points used in g(x) is influencing the shape of h(x).
Figure 1 shows what I mean better than I can describe it:
[image: Figure 1: Influence of the number of points used in the response function on the convoluted curves]
Then, my question is: what is the correct number of points to use in g(x)?

I've used python and numpy to do the work. The code I'm using is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

# Full Width at Half Maximum - also known as Instrumental Broadening
FWHM = 0.678

filename = "Input_Data_File.dat"
DataX,DataY = [],[]
with open(filename) as Data:
  reader = csv.reader(Data,delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace=True)
  for row in reader:
    DataX.append(float(row[0]))
    DataY.append(float(row[1]))

# The f(x) data:
DataX = np.array(DataX)
DataY = np.array(DataY)
lx = len(DataX)

x1 = np.linspace(-FWHM*2.0,FWHM*2.0,num=int(lx*(0.1))) #len(x) = 10% of len(DataX)
x2 = np.linspace(-FWHM*2.0,FWHM*2.0,num=int(lx*(0.02))) #len(x) = 2% of len(DataX)
x3 = np.linspace(-FWHM*2.0,FWHM*2.0,num=int(lx*(0.2))) #len(x) = 20% of len(DataX)

# Response function - Gaussian type
G1 = np.exp(-4*np.log(2)*((x1/FWHM)**2))
G2 = np.exp(-4*np.log(2)*((x2/FWHM)**2))
G3 = np.exp(-4*np.log(2)*((x3/FWHM)**2))

# Performing the convolutions
H1 = np.convolve(G1,DataY,'same')
H2 = np.convolve(G2,DataY,'same')
H3 = np.convolve(G3,DataY,'same')

# Normalizing convoluted functions
H1 = H1/max(H1)
H2 = H2/max(H2)
H3 = H3/max(H3)

# Normalizing DataY as Y
Y = DataY/max(DataY)

plt.plot(DataX,Y,'y--', label="Input function / f(x)")
plt.plot(DataX,H1,'r-', label="#points: {}".format(len(x1)))
plt.plot(DataX,H2,'g-', label="#points: {}".format(len(x2)))
plt.plot(DataX,H3,'b-', label="#points: {}".format(len(x3)))
plt.xlabel("x / DataXt")
plt.ylabel("Normalized intensity")
plt.ylim(-0.05,1.05)
plt.title("Influence of #points of 'Response\nfunction' in convoluted curves")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.savefig("Convoluted_curves.png")
plt.show()
```

And the data file I used as "Input_Data_File.dat" can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/gwfbubN6).

Answer (score 0):

By experimental verification, I can conclude that the correct number of points to be used in the response function g(x) is the one in which the step most closely approximates the step of the input function f(x).

So in the python code of the question, the best option would be to use *numpy.arange* with the correct step instead of *numpy.linspace*.

Comment: Unfortunately I've not found (yet) any reference to this conclusion in the discrete/numerical convolution theory. If anyone knows a reference to support this, please let me know.